# django - django-taggit form with django-chosen

Tags: django, django-models, widget, django-forms, django-taggit

I would like to use django-taggit. I use Bootstrap to generate the form.
I use the widget as below for my form fields.
Questions are linked to several items for now, and I would like to link them to several tags as well.

forms.py:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

create = False
no_results = _("No results matched")

class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ("content", "status", "items")
    widgets = {
        "content": Textarea(attrs={
            "class": "span4",
            "placeholder": _("Ask something specific."),
            "rows": 1}),
        "status": ChosenSelect(),
        "items": ChosenSelectMultiple(
            attrs={"class": "span4", "rows": 1},
            overlay=_("Pick a product."),
        ),
    }
```

How to integrate the tags in my form widget, given I would like to use ChosenSelectMultiple for the tags as well? (I need the question to be linked to several items and several tags)

models.py:

```
class Question(Content):
content = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_("content"))
tags = TaggableManager()

class Content(models.Model):
items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name=_("products"))
```

I thought I could use TagField and ChosenSelectMultiple to handle it in my widget, but I have no idea how to do that.